# jquery each function for dynamically elements

Tags: jquery, iteration

I am dynamically adding a class to my code using Jquery's `.attr('class', 'show')`. But when I use `.each()` function like this:

```
$('.show a').each(function() {
    alert(0);
});
```

it doesen't work.

I works when I added the 'show' class manually.

How can I do this dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

Use "addClass" instead of trying to set the class via "attr()".

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that you're adding a class to an existing element. If so it may work better if you used:

```
$('.myElement').addClass('show');
```

If you need to add an element to the dom, that's a completely different matter.

**EDIT:**

To address the new info you gave, there are two things to change:

First, use addClass:

```
$('#existing div:first').show().addClass('show');
```

Second, you forgot the . before 'show' for your each. It should be `('.show a')`:

```
            $('.show a').each(function() {
                alert(0);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have existing element div.

```
$('#somewhere').click(function() {                  

                $('#existing div:first').show().attr('class', 'show');

                $('show a').each(function() {
                    alert(0);
                });
});
```

My code: 
`<div id="existing">
    <div>
        <a href="#">a1</a>
        <a href="#">a2</a
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">b1</a>
        <a href="#">b2</a>
    </div>`

I tried .addClass and .attr...

Comment: You're new here, so just want to let you know that if you wish to clarify your question, it is better to edit the original question, or add a comment like this to one of the answers. I've edited my answer to address the problem.